# Select two columns from two tables and order by their values DESC

Tags: php, mysql

With this code I'm getting news from the database and order it by column "views":

```
          <?php
          $getnewsinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5");
    while($newsinforow = mysql_fetch_array($getnewsinfo))
    {
    $newsid = $newsinforow['id'];
    $title = $newsinforow['title'];
    $author = $newsinforow['author'];
    $date = date('d.m.Y', $newsinforow['date']);
    $picture = $newsinforow['picture'];
    $picture_desc = $newsinforow['picture_desc'];
    $category = $newsinforow['category'];
    $text = $newsinforow['text'];
?>
```

Now I want to order the news by views and by the number of comments, but I have no idea how.
Here is my database structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `picture_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news_comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `news_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;
```

I also want to ask you... do you have any comments on the code and database structure ?

Comment: First to say mysql_* is deprecated and the guy should use mysqli! .. Now lets take a loog at the question ;p

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql

```
SELECT n.*,count(nc.id) as cnt FROM news as n, news_comments as nc where n.id = nc.news_id group by nc.news_id ORDER BY views DESC,cnt DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: It's works, thanks.
Can I order it first by views and than by number of comments ?
In the moment it's ordering first by number of comments.